# Find the intersaction of two equations

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, intersection

I would like to find the intersection between (eq1, eq2) and (eq1, eq3) and show that point with the dotted line on each axis. This code does not give me the exact point but just an approximation. I do not understand where am I doing mistake.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = []
h = []
j = []
point = []

for x in range(25):
    eq1 = x * 185 * 3
    eq2 = 11930 - (12502 / 6) + (x * 185) / 6
    eq3 = 11930 - (12502 / 3) + (x * 185) / 6
    point.append(x)
    f.append(eq1)
    h.append(eq2)
    j.append(eq3)


plt.plot(point, f)
plt.plot(point, h)
plt.plot(point, j)
plt.legend(loc='lower right', fontsize=10)

idx1 = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(np.array(f) - np.array(h)))).flatten()
idx2 = idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(np.array(f) - np.array(j)))).flatten()
plt.plot(np.array(point)[idx1+1], np.array(h)[idx1+1], 'ro')
plt.plot(np.array(point)[idx2+1], np.array(j)[idx2+1], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a perfect example of a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Very nicely asked question. Keep it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues here:

1. Firstly, your code is unnecessarily long. Make use of NumPy arrays to simplify things. Since NumPy is a dependency of `matplotlib`, you are not overkilling by importing NumPy.
2. You need to make a very dense mesh of points between 0 and 25 to get more accurate intersection points. Use `linspace` with 1000 points for example.

As you can see, with arrays, you don't need to use for loop, neither you need to initialize empty lists and then append values one by one.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 25, 1000)

f = x * 185 * 3
h = 11930 - (12502 / 6) + (x * 185) / 6
j = 11930 - (12502 / 3) + (x * 185) / 6

plt.plot(x, f, label='f')
plt.plot(x, h, label='h')
plt.plot(x, j, label='j')
plt.legend(loc='lower right', fontsize=12)

idx1 = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(np.array(f) - np.array(h)))).flatten()
idx2 = idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(np.array(f) - np.array(j)))).flatten()
plt.plot(x[idx1+1], h[idx1+1], 'ro')
plt.plot(x[idx2+1], j[idx2+1], 'ro')

plt.vlines(x[idx1+1], 0, h[idx1+1], linestyle='--')
plt.vlines(x[idx2+1], 0, j[idx2+1], linestyle='--')

plt.hlines(h[idx1+1], 0, x[idx1+1], linestyle='--')
plt.hlines(j[idx2+1], 0, x[idx2+1], linestyle='--')

plt.xlim(0, None)
plt.ylim(0, None)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your tips. So, the second part of my question is how can I show the x and y value of that point on each axis by dot line? I hope I ask it clearly.

Comment: @fsrfyama I will add that to my answer

Comment: @fsrfyama Glad to help!